# Mongoose: only show populated results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to return a result that is filtered by populate

Schema for a collection

```
{
  myObjects: [{
    obj: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: myObject }
  }]
}
```

Schema for myObject

```
{
  name: { type: String },
  active: { type: Boolean }
}
```

So

```
.find().populate('myObjects.obj')
```

This returns back results like so

```
[
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }, 
      { obj: { name: 'Stacy', active: false } },
      { obj: { name: 'James', active: false } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'James', active: false } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }, 
      { obj: { name: 'James', active: false } }
    ]
  }
]
```

At this point, I want to say "Only show me those where active: true"

so I do...

```
.find().populate({ path: 'myObjects.obj', match: { active: true })
```

Except this returns back the following

```
[
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [

    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } } }
    ]
  }
]
```

There's one myObjects that contains an empty array. How do I exclude this from the result so I'm only receiving back

```
[
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } }
    ]
  },
  { myObjects: 
    [
      { obj: { name: 'Adam', active: true } } }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: should I do something like `result = result.filter(function(val) { return val.myObjects.length; })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to populate in mongoose only if ref is not null - not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165302/trying-to-populate-in-mongoose-only-if-ref-is-not-null-not-working)